# Fonts larger than \Huge?

Tags: fontsize

How can I make text that is larger than the size of the output of `{\Huge ...}`?

I would like to be able to make text arbitrarily large (even if that is done by some suboptimal scaling routine).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use the [Memoir document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir). It provides two things that are relevant to your question:

#### More Base Font Sizes

---

The standard LaTeX document classes only allow you to choose 10pt, 11pt or 12point as the "base" font size for your document.  Memoir provides many more choices: 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt, 25pt, 30pt, 36pt, 48pt and 60pt.  Since all font size declarations are affected by the base font size, using a bigger base font size will make `\Huge` render in a bigger font.

#### The \HUGE Font Size

---

For when it absolutely has to be bigger than `\Huge`, crank it to 11 with `\HUGE`.

[image]

Comment: The answer was great, and the xkcd made it even better!

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Using memoir is a total hack.  But it makes sense that someone writing his memoirs would need a larger font ...

Comment: Is this an answer? Given a base font size, how do you obtain text larger than \Huge? Still unanswered...

Comment: The following sets global font size to 36pt:

\documentclass[36pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}

Comment: +1, but just as a nitpick, switching to a new document class is usually overkill and may also bring new changes and headaches. Further, if you're not writing a paper/book/... to begin with, but using (say) `beamer` instead, it'll be outright impossible.

Answer (score 95):

If you use Type 1 fonts (e.g., package `mathptmx` or `mathpazo`), you can simply use the `\fontsize` command with large point sizes:

```
{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Foo!}
```

(The first parameter (50) is font size. The second parameter (60) is line spacing. An appropriate line spacing depends on the font. Something like 1.2 times font size is commonly used with CM fonts. But it does not really matter if you are typesetting just one line of text.)

Comment: Could you add an explanation what the meaning of the first and 2nd argument is (50 and 60)? Width times height in points?

Comment: @JukkaSuomela: Is 50 the biggest font size? I'm trying to get the [header](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/about/matte.pdf) as big as possible ([source](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/latex/matte.tex)). Terve!

Comment: How / Where to check if the fonts I'm using are indeed `Type 1` (or not) ?

Comment: You can use this with any type of font, not just type1, you may need to modify the fd files (eg fix-cm package in the case of cm fonts)

Comment: Tried to play with line spacing parameter but did not see it having any effect.

Comment: @Jukka Suomela: how can I change the font type in your example?

Comment: This eventually is capped. I can't go any bigger than like 20 size font.

Comment: Thank you @Jukka Suomela! I want this for presenting a new kanji word on my book, but bigger than \HUGE.

Answer (score 56):

A quick search on CTAN turned up [`anyfontsize`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize).  To quote the description:

> The package allows the to user select any font size (via e.g. `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont`), even those sizes that are not listed in the .fd file. If such a size is requested, LaTeX will search for and select the nearest listed size; anyfontsize will then scale the font to the size actually requested.
>
> Similar functionality is available for the CM family (type1cm), for the EC family (type1ec), or for either computer modern encoding (fix-cm); the present package generalises the facility.

Answer (score 51):

The `\resizebox` command (from `graphicx` package) is convenient if you want to produce, e.g., a title that fills the entire page width:

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\itshape Foo!}
```

Comment: That's a neat solution...

Comment: Keep in mind, that [linebreaks require a workaround](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25739/resizebox-doesnt-respect-linebreaks)

Comment: This is much easier and to the point for what I'm trying to do as well :)

Answer (score 23):

To extend on @Yiannis and the comment by @isomorphismes
I also needed to have the fix-cm package loaded

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}    

\usepackage{fix-cm}    

\makeatletter
\newcommand\HUGE{\@setfontsize\Huge{50}{60}}
\makeatother    


\begin{document}

\Huge Huge text

\HUGE HUGE text

\end{document}
```

Comment: This was the only fix that worked for me!

Comment: The `fix-cm` docs state that the package should be loaded with `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 21):

In your class add:

```
%% Define a HUGE 
\newcommand\HUGE{\@setfontsize\Huge{38}{47}}
```

Comment: In order to make this work, I needed to preface it with `\makeatletter` and postface it with `\makeatother`.

Answer (score 17):

In XeTeX (using fontspec) you can use system fonts many of which have a "Scale" attribute you can set to a large number.  For instance, in one document I have this line for a largeish Japanese font:

```
\newfontinstance\bigkanafont[Color=000000,Scale=2.5]{Hiragino Mincho Pro W3}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to http://www.mostlymaths.net/2009/03/big-fonts-in-latex.html, you can use the [`fix-cm`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=fix-cm) package to get arbitrary-size fonts. In fact, [searching CTAN for `fix-cm`](http://www.ctan.org/cgi-bin/search.py?metadataSearch=fix-cm) seems to give a few different packages that provide this functionality. I've never used any of them myself so I couldn't tell you which ones might work or not, but it shouldn't be hard to try them.

Comment: Yeah, searching CTAN for fix-cm gives three results: type1cm, which recommends fix-cm, fix-cm itself, and the more general anyfontsize that's in Andrew Stacey's answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
\scalebox{2}{\fontsize{32pt}{0pt}\selectfont \textbf{Your text}}
```

This piece of code worked for me and also provided better control over the size by adjusting the scale factor

Comment: Better use a scalable font than scaling up.

Comment: A solution that actually works...

Answer (score 3):

There is also a package called [`moresize`](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/special/moresize.pdf) that can be useful.

And another trick is to use, 10pt, 11pt, or 12pt but with a proportional, smaller "`geometry`" than the one desired.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my ancient `moresize` package. It does not provide *arbitrary* fontsizes however, just some more, so that one could try the EC font design sizes for example, and it can tune math scriptsize settings that should bring multiline headlines with math in a better shape. To solve the OP's problem, I'd go with one of the other recommendations.

Comment: @ccorn Anyway, `moresize` is perfect for adding `\HUGE` without changing document class. ;)