# resizebox doesn't respect linebreaks?

Tags: line-breaking, scaling

I'm trying to scale some text up. It seems like `\resizebox` (from `graphicx`?) and `\adjustbox` (from the `adjustbox` package) ignore line breaks:

```
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{Hello\\
world}
```

Is there a way to scale things up that respects line breaks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both use a horizontal savebox to store and then scale the content. You can't have line breaks in this kind of boxes. While manual line breaks would be somehow possible (e.g. using some vertical stacked `\hbox`es), automatic line breaking only works when a specific width is given.

The `adjustbox` package supports a `minipage=<length>` key which automatically places a `minipage` around the content. Then line breaks will work.
It also has a `tabular` key, which also allows the stacking of lines, e.g. using `tabular=@{}l@{}` to left-align all lines without any separation on the right and left of the table. So your example could now be written as `\adjustbox{tabular=@{}l@{},width=5cm}{Hello\\world\\}`. Note that the trailing `\\` is mandatory when `tabular` is used.

You can also use `\shortstack{Hello\\world}` (maybe with `\strut`s included) to get the line breaking. Then there is the `minibox` package which provides a quick `tabular` as macro `\minibox`.

Comment: `shortstack[l]{Hello\\world}` for left aligned shortstack. By default it's centering.

Answer (score 18):

Use a tabular inside the box.

```
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{%
 \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  hello\\ world
 \end{tabular}%
 }
```

Comment: Your code did not work for me. What worked though was `\resizebox{5cm}{!}{` ...

Comment: @Florian: You are right, there was typo. I corrected it.