# \obeylines in \resizebox

Tags: graphics, minipage, scaling

I learnt from [resizebox doesn't respect linebreaks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25739/resizebox-doesnt-respect-linebreaks) that `\resizebox` contents had to be wrapped in a minipage to get newlines; indeed, it works:

```
\resizebox{20em}{!}
  {\begin{minipage}{10em}
     lorem\\
     ipsum\\
     tex.stackexchange
   \end{minipage}}
```

And it works with `\par`, as well:

```
\resizebox{20em}{!}
  {\begin{minipage}{10em}
     lorem\par
     ipsum\par
     tex.stackexchange
   \end{minipage}}
```

But not with `\obeylines`? What gives?

```
\resizebox{20em}{!}
  {\begin{minipage}{10em}
     \obeylines{}
     lorem
     ipsum
     tex.stackexchange
   \end{minipage}}
```

How can I use `\obeylines` in a `\resizebox`?

Comment: `\obeylines` is similar to  `\verb` and doesn't work in any command argument. Just put it before the `\resizebox`

Comment: Isn't `\obeylines` just a catcode change? Why doesn't that work in a command with arguments? I ran into this problem because an environment that I use calls `\obeylines`, and I can't really move that outside of the environment :/  In any case, please make this an answer, and I'll be happy to accept it :)

Comment: @it's _because_ they are a catcode change that obeylines and verb do not work in command arguments

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explaining :) I wonder how `listings`, `fancyvrb`, and the like do it, then. Don't they use catcode changes to preserve spaces, lines, etc?

Comment: yes and listings has the same restrictions as verb, it can't be used in the argument of another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the setup before the argument is scanned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

{\obeylines\resizebox{20em}{!}%
  {\begin{minipage}{10em}%
     lorem
     ipsum
     tex.stackexchange
   \end{minipage}}}
\end{document}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's an alternative solution? The environment that I'm using does the obeylines call, so duplicating it seems wasteful... maybe something based on `savebox`es?

Comment: @Clément `\obeylines` is only a couple of assignments, doing it twice is no cost at all really.

Comment: @Clément I deleted the (now) spurious `\par` from my answer.