# Fonts issues in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontsize

I would like to know what is the right way to define all the text font as a specific size. I use `\documentclass[20pt]{article}` but it won't change the font size in xelatex. And these symbols (`"` and `'`) are not Times fonts and now matter how I changed the fonts , they look the same. Here is the min working code. I would like to know what is the right way to address font selection in xelatex. Can I get like this ?
[image]    Instead of this ?        [image]

```
 %!TEX TS-program = xelatex

 \documentclass[20pt]{article}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{mathspec}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \setmainfont{Times}
 \setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Times}
 \usepackage{titling}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
 \doublespacing
 \titleformat{\section}{\singlespacing\fontsize{20}{24}\bfseries\rmfamily\uppercase} {\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
  \begin{document}
 \section{"check"}
"just checking" this is a "check" and 'check'. 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fonts larger than \Huge?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265/fonts-larger-than-huge)

Comment: To get the proper quotes, add the option `Mapping=tex-text` to your `\setmainfont` command. Opening quotes are typed with `\`` and `\`\``; closing quotes are typed with `'` and `''`. Don't use `"`, since it has incorrect spacing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case if you are tied to `article` document class, here are the two options:

**Option-1**

You can use `scrextend` package, that extends the facilities (like font sizes) of `KOMA-script classes to other classes:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}         %%% this line
\changefontsizes[24pt]{20pt}   %%% and this line
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Times New Roman}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\doublespacing
\titleformat{\section}{\singlespacing\fontsize{20}{24}\bfseries\rmfamily\uppercase} {\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{``check''}
``just checking'' this is a ``check'' and `check'.
\end{document}
```

**Option-2**

You can use `extsizes` package, which is a package version of `extarticle` mentioned by Karl Koeller in his answer.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{scrextend}
%\changefontsizes[24pt]{20pt}
\usepackage[20pt]{extsizes} %%% this line
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Times New Roman}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\doublespacing
\titleformat{\section}{\singlespacing\fontsize{20}{24}\bfseries\rmfamily\uppercase} {\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{``check''}
``just checking'' this is a ``check'' and `check'.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Change fontsize inside float in KOMA class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223584) ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The `article` class only supports `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`.

You can use the `extarticle` (extended `article`) class which supports `20pt`.

In the following MWE I've changed "Times" to "Times New Roman" and I get the correct quotes using `Ligatures=TeX` option, but you have to use the standard LaTeX way for double quotes.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Times New Roman}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\doublespacing
\titleformat{\section}{\singlespacing\fontsize{20}{24}\bfseries\rmfamily\uppercase} {\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{``check''}
``just checking'' this is a ``check'' and `check'.
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you want `"..."` to behave this way, you can add these two lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

Comment: I thought if I use xelatex , I would get the identical fonts I can get in other places like the image I just updated. Is it not possible even though I use the same fonts? Thanks,

Comment: @Aung I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\documentclass[fontsize=20pt]{scrartcl}
```