# Increasing the fontsize in a TikZ picture beyond \HUGE

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I am using the follow code to create name signs for my students. How can I increase the size of the font beyond `\Huge`? I'd like to scale the size of the word without scaling the whole picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=0.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {Donald Tiberius Duck,Mickey Sherlock Mouse}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
[mybox/.style={rectangle,black,xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,minimum width=0.99\textwidth,font=\Huge\bfseries,draw=black,very thick,align=center, minimum height=0.475\textheight}]
\node at (0,0) [mybox] {\x};
\node at (0,0.475\textheight) [mybox] {};
\end{tikzpicture}\clearpage}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fonts larger than \Huge?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265/fonts-larger-than-huge)

Comment: Do you mean `\Huge` or `\HUGE`? (You write both.)

Comment: I meant `\HUGE`, however the solution below works fine. I use now the integrated font features in the KOMA classes: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=3107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\fontsize{50}{60}` in  `font=\fontsize{40}{48}\bfseries,` with a scalable font (`\selectfont` is needed if no `\bfseries` is used.). With `\usepackage{lmodern}` you get

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=0.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor,lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {Donald Tiberius Duck,Mickey Sherlock Mouse}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
[mybox/.style={rectangle,black,xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,minimum width=0.99\textwidth,font=\fontsize{40}{48}\bfseries,draw=black,very thick,align=center, minimum height=0.475\textheight}]
\node at (0,0) [mybox] {\x};
\node at (0,0.475\textheight) [mybox,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}\clearpage}

\end{document}
```