# Page size and bold type

Tags: page

How can I make a latex document where the page is 13cm wide and 21cm long ? I also want to use bold type.  Is there a limit on how large the font can be ?

This is what I got

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}  % Accesses \blacksquare
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % Programming tools

\title{First document}
\author{God}
\date{September 2022}

\signature{God}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: An attempt to show a layout would help this question.

Comment: If I change the geometry, would I need to change the `a4paper` declaration in `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}` ?

Comment: `paperheight=13cm, paperwidth=21cm` as geometry options. Of course, `a4paper` is contradictory with this sizes and it  should not be any place. Maybe you want really the A5 format?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224685/increasing-the-fontsize-in-a-tikz-picture-beyond-huge

Comment: `12pt` is the largest base size supported out-of-the-box by the standard classes. Of course, you then get larger sizes when things like `\large` are in effect, but the base size is limited to 10,11 or 12pt.