# crazy small fonts for a formulabook

Tags: fontsize

I am setting a "formula book" to gather my formulas I need during exams.
For that I use a `[a5paper, 8pt]{article}` but in most cases I use even `\footnotesize` because it looks better in my eyes and it gives me more space on a small A5 page.
`extsize` does not suit me because the [manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extsizes.pdf) says its only for 8-20pt.

I was not able to find a definition how to do define that permanently.

Is there any way to set the `\normalsize` to the size of `\footnotesize` or define `\footnotesize` as default?

Comment: Koma uses \input{size10.clo} to initialize 10pt font (for example).  This is a relatively long file and sets many parameters.

Comment: yes i already read about extsizes but it clearly says it only goes from 8-20pt. So this is not dupplicate.
 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extsizes.pdf

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [Fonts larger than `\Huge`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300/5764) Add `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` and specify the font size you want `\fontsize{5pt}{7pt}\selectfont`.

Comment: What I meant is that you can create a new file (size6.clo) by editing and renaming one of the existing ones.  You are the best judge of what is aesthetically pleasing for that font size.