# How to change title font size in secsty?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I have the below code for a LaTex document on overleaf. I am really happy with it, however I would like to be able to increase the size of font on the main Title, without changing anything else. Is this possible with the \secsty package

Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.25in,hmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}               % Times Roman
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet} % Helvetica

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\large\sffamily}
%\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[nosectionbib,numberedbib]{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\refname{REFERENCES}}
\begin{document}
\raggedright

\hrule
\begin{center}
\huge\bfseries\sffamily Title is using arial
\end{center}
\hrule

\section*{ABSTRACT now uses arial}

Correctly using Times Roman 

\section{INTRODUCTION now uses arial}

Correctly using Times Roman


\end{document}
```

Comment: And by "main title" you're referring to "Title is using arial"? So you're looking for something bigger than `\huge`...

Comment: You don't need [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) for this. You can use `\Huge` instead of `\huge`, or if you want to go even bigger than that, you can just follow the suggestions listed here: [Fonts larger than `\Huge`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265/5764)

Comment: @Werner thank you my friend I used the \usepackage{mathptmx}  package which allowed me to increase the sixe of the font. Thanks for the link 1

Comment: Both the `times` and `mathptmx` packages are deprecated. Better to use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

Comment: Please don't edit your questions to include answers. It makes things really very confusing for other users.