# How can I get this chapter title format?

Tags: formatting, chapters

I'd like my chapters to look like this:
[image]

(if it helps, the picture is from the Princeton Lectures in Analysis textbook series by Elias Stein) I know how to insert the quote (using the `epigraph` package) but I can't find how to style the chapter title like that. I've tried reading the manuals for `fncychap` and `titlesec` (I am using the latter already, to make the section titles smaller) but I couldn't understand how to properly use them. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Here's a MWE so you can make a quick copy-paste to your computer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\title{MWE}
\author{nelichu}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Measure Theory}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino font
\title{MWE}
\author{nelichu}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Huge}{{\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\thechapter}}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Large}{{\Huge\thechapter}}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Measure Theory}
Normal text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used Palatino font because it looks like TeX's default serif font cannot be arbitrarily increased in size. I have referred to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/716) for the same.

If you are okay with smaller chapter font, you can also try to use this instead:

```tex
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Large}{{\Huge\thechapter}}{1em}{}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I used the `anyfontsize` package and was able to arbitrarily increase the default font's size. Great